# Script to toggle touchpad

Tags: bash

This sequence properly shows whether the `TouchpadOff` option for `synclient` is on or not (outputs either a `0` or a `1`):

```
synclient | grep 'TouchpadOff' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print substr($3, 1)}'
```

Trying to make a keyboard shortcut to toggle the touchpad with a basic script based on that line, I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PADOFF=$(synclient | grep 'TouchpadOff' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print substr($3, 1)}')
if [ "$PADOFF" == "0" ]
then
    synclient TouchpadOff=1
else
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
fi.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of `substr($3, 1)` — isn't that the same as `$3`?

AWK alone can do the work of `grep`, `tail`, and negation.  I would write it this way:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient | awk '/TouchpadOff/ { off=int($3) }
                                         END           { print !off }')
```